# Uploading Custom Google Maps created in App to a web page

Tags: android, google-maps, uploading

I am currently creating an android app in which users can add overlay items to a Google map. The goal is to have these customized maps be saved and uploaded to an internet community. I can't figure out how to do this, but would really appreciate learning how to either embed the app (and thus the customized map) into a web page or just save the map and upload it.
Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [KML](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) it's a xml markup language to exchange geospatial data ("maps"). Google Earth, Google Maps and other applications can read, write and display kml files.